# Why isn't my title being inserted into my database?

Tags: node.js, database, express, server, ejs

I'm trying to insert the title from my input form into my `caption` column in my database and then display it with the post. The image and delete buttons display, however the title does not.

Here is my route in my server.js:

```
app.post('/newPost', isLoggedIn, uploads.single('inputFile'), (req, res) => {
  console.log('On POST route');

  // get an input from user
  let file = req.file.path;
  console.log(file);

  
  cloudinary.uploader.upload(file, (result) => {
    console.log(result);
        
    db.post.create({
          caption: req.body.title,
          image_url: result.url,
          userId: req.body.id
        })
        
    // Render result page with image
  }).then((post) => res.render('index', { image: result.url }));
})
```

Here is my `newPost.ejs` which contains the form:

```
<div class="postSection">
    <form action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="title" placeholder="Write a Caption:" id="postText">
        <input type="file" name="inputFile" id="inputFile"> 
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="postSubmit" value="Post">
    </form>
</div>
```

And, finally here is my `index.ejs` page in which it will display:

```
<div>
    <% posts.forEach(function(post) { %>
        <h1><%= post.caption %></h1>
        <img class="images" width="700px" height="500px" src="<%= post.image_url %>" alt="uploaded image"> 
        <form action="/<%= post.id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
            <input id="deleteButton" class="btn-danger" type="submit" value="Remove idea" >
        </form>
        <br>
    <% }) %>
</div>
```

Can anyone spot why the title isn't being inserted into my database and also why it isn't displaying?

Comment: try req.body[0]

Answer (score 0):

One option to debug is console.log the req.body and search for the text you sent as the title.

I think that the title is in req.body.postText or you should add a name tag to your title input and that will be the name in your req.body.

Let me know if this helps!